# Authentication in gogole action

Tags: actions-on-google

First of all, I am very new to google action and my question may sound little dumb.

I am trying to build an action using **action sdk** which calls  my websevice.
Websevice is running my custom NLP code  to process the user's queries. Once user has finished the conversation, it sends mail to the user.

Problem is I am not able to understand how to authenticate the user.  Once user is authenticated, I can send the email to that user.

Please guide me on user authentication part.Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by 'authenticate the user', exactly? Are you using [account linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/)?

Comment: Somehow I want to get the username or email address of the user who is using that skill, so that at the end I can send email.

Comment: Right. Well, using the built-in account linking framework is the only way to do that, unless you literally ask for the email address as part of the conversation.